# How to check that logo present in the email (javax mail)

Tags: java, selenium, email-validation

I need a help again) I check email notifications and need to check that logo is present in email, how can I do this?

1. Keep expected logo.png and compare with logo from email? How to do this?
2. Just to check that logo is present, don't compare with excpected

For me second variant is good as well

This code always return false

```
part.getContentType().contains("image/")
```

here screen with email
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIiyG.png)

Comment: What datatype is 'part' ? .getContentType() can be applied for URLConnection.

Comment: datatype from email message - 'text'
I don't know how to get image/logo(

Comment: .getContentType() you can use to find out a HTTP responce contains an image, but in Selenium this approach just won't work. Selenium does not send/catch requests/responce. It just operates the browser. You need to locate the image as webelement and find out it is an image (has some image specific property).